# Showing system contains peroidic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the IVP for the $2$-dimensional dynamical system ($X=[0, \infty )^2$) $$\dot{x_1}=a-x_1-\frac{4x_1x_2}{1+x_1^2}$$ $$\dot{x_2}=bx_1 \bigg( 1- \frac{x_2}{1+x_1^2} \bigg)$$ for all $t \in I$, and $\textbf x (0)=(x_{10}, x_{20}) \in [0, \infty )^2$, with $a,b >0$.

Show that for certain $a$, $b$, and $c$, there exists an invariant region
$$\{f(x_1, x_2) \in X : 0 < x_1 < a, \, \, 0 < x_2 < c \}$$
that contains a periodic orbit for the dynamical system.

My attempt:

So we have a rectangle and we have to choose $a,b,c$ such that the flow always remains within the rectangle. Let's consider each edge and corner of the rectangle. Imagine our graph to be $x_1$ as the horizontal axis and $x_2$ as the vertical.

At corner $(0,0)$: $\dot x_1=a$, $\dot x_2 =0$ so at this point, flow is directed $x_1$ direction so this is inside the region.

At corner $(0,c)$: $\dot x_1=a$, $\dot x_2 =0$ so at this point, flow is directed $x_1$ direction so this is inside the region.

At line $x_1=0$ so on points $(0,l)$ with $l \in (0,c)$: $\dot x_1=a$, $\dot x_2 =0$ so at this point, flow is directed $x_1$ direction so this is inside the region.

At corner $(a,c)$: $$\dot x_1 =-\frac{4ac}{1+a^2}<0, \, \, \forall a,c$$

$$\dot x_2 =ba \bigg( 1- \frac{c}{1+a^2} \bigg)$$ with $ba>0, \, \, \forall a,b$ but we need the sign of $\dot x_2$ to be $\leq 0$ and this is dependent on the sign of the following (so we WANT the following): $$ 1- \frac{c}{1+a^2} \leq 0$$ so then the flow at this corner will go negative $x_1$ direction or down within the region. Either way, flow will still be in the region.

At line $x_2=0$ so on points $(q,0)$ with $q \in (0,a)$: $\dot x_1 =a-q >0, \, \, \forall a,q$, and $\dot x_2 =bq>0$. So the flow is directed in the region.

At line $x_1=a$ so on points $(a,p)$ with $p \in (0,c)$: $$\dot x_1 = - \frac{4ap}{1+a^2}<0, \, \, \forall a,p$$ 
$$\dot x_2 =ba \bigg( 1- \frac{p}{1+a^2} \bigg)$$ We are unsure on the sign of this but regardless the flow will remain in the region since $\dot x_1 <0$.

At line $\dot x_2 =c$, so on points $(t,c)$ with $t \in (0,a)$: $$\dot x_1 = a-t -\frac{4tc}{1+t^2}<0 $$

$$\dot x_2 =bt \bigg( 1- \frac{c}{1+t^2} \bigg)$$ We are unsure on the signs of both of these but we WANT $\dot x_2 \leq 0$ and then regardless of the sign of $\dot x_1$, the flow will remain in the region.

So we need the flowing inequalities to hold: $$1- \frac{c}{1+a^2} \leq 0$$ $$1- \frac{c}{1+t^2} \leq 0$$ Choose $c=66$ and $a=8$ and then they hold.

Next we need our fixed point to be out of the region and this happens when $$1 + \frac{a^2}{25} < c$$ and this is true for our chosen values of $a$ and $c$. Hence by Poincare-Bendixon theorem, there exists a periodic orbit.

IS THIS CORRECT? PLEASE COMMENT!!

I think we have to use this:

Poincare-Bendixon: Consider $\dot x = f(x)$ with $f \in C^1(X)$ (continuous on first differential) and $X \subset \mathbb R^2$. If the forward orbit, $O^+(x_0)$ (for $x_0 > X$) is
contained within a closed bounded set $D$ containing no fixed points, then
$\omega (x_0)$ contains a periodic orbit.

Generalized Poincare-Bendixon: Let the hypothesis of the above hold, except now, let $D$ contain fixed
points $p_1, ..., p_N$. Then $\omega (x_0)$ is one of the following;

1) a fixed point $p_i$.

2) a periodic orbit.

3) a finite number of fixed points $p_i$ , and a countable number of
homoclinic/ heteroclinic orbits between $p_i$ and $p_j$.

Comment: have you tried to transform these to polar coordinates?

Comment: The OP is almost certainly asked to apply a theorem in their notes rather than embark on horrendous (and not very enlightening) computations.

Comment: @Did Yeah I think we do. I wrote the relevant theorem. So am i not meant to turn them into polars? And do we have to choose our $a$, $b$, $c$ such that there would be no fixed points?

Comment: "am i not meant to turn them into polars?" No. "do we have to choose our a, b, c such that there would be no fixed points?" You first have to choose $c$, for $(a,b)$ fixed, such that $D=[0,a]\times[0,c]$ is invariant by the dynamics in the sense that if $x(0)$ is in $D$ then $x(t)$ is still in $D$ for every $t\geqslant0$. To ensure that, it suffices that, at every point on the boundary of $D$, the vector field *enters* $D$. No problem here. The second phase is to choose $(a,b)$ such that there is a cycle around the fixed point, and for that, Jonas' indication is the way to go.

Comment: @Did But I guess what I said above makes the set given not invariant right? What exactly does invariant mean? To make it invariant (from what I guess) is that the fixed point has to lie within the region so we can say let $1+a^2/25 \leq c$ so that it is 'invariant' right? But then what? I have no idea what is being said in the answers below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Find the directions of the vector field along the sides of the rectangle $[0,a]\times[0,c]$, for some carefully chosen $c$. For example, along the side $x_1=0$ you have $\dot x_1=a$ and $\dot x_2=0$, showing that the vector field points inside the rectangle. Similarly, for $x_2=0$ you have $\dot x_1=a-x_1$ and $\dot x_2=bx_1$, and again the vector field points inside the rectangle (you see the pattern).

After that study the vector field in a neighborhood of the equilibrium point.

A minor comment about the wording: you should really write "forward invariant" instead of "invariant", and "equilibrium point" instead of "fixed point".

Comment: Though I myself prefer to use "fixed point" only for discrete dynamics, it's a common (mis)usage. It's even in present in [MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPoint.html).

Comment: @Evgeny Quite true. That makes me remind some discussions I had with Eric Weisstein many years ago on mistakes in his "encyclopaedia".

Comment: And what did Eric Weisstein say? It seems that MathWorld is not the only source of 'confusion'.

Comment: @snowman As stated in your question, you are supposed to find $a,b,c$, and so you can choose them. Anyways, you last inequality has $c$ in it, which is fine.

Comment: @Jonas Hello, PLEASE could you have a look at my attempt on the main post and comment on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @snowman The first part is fine, although we don't need to mention the corners (since by continuity it is sufficient to consider the sides). The second part is not fine: you want the equilibrium point to be inside the rectangle and you need to show that all goes away from the point in some sufficiently small neighborhood.

Comment: @Jonas Could you tell me how to do the second part please.

Comment: @Jonas Also, the theorem says that no fixed points should be in the region D so I am quite confused why it has to be in the region rather than out...

Comment: You should linearize around the equilibrium point and show that both eigenvalues have positive real part. It this doesn't happen then some other argument needs to be found, but this is the first thing to try.

Comment: I see, easy to fix: the region should be the rectangle minus a small disk around the critical point. If what I suggested about the eigenvalues holds, then this region will be invariant in the sense that all that starts there will remain there for positive time.

Comment: @Jonas I am really confused now... So are we meant to choose values for a, b, c such that the critical point is in or out the region we are given which is $\{(x_1,x_2) : 0<x_1<a, \, \, 0<x_2 <c \}$???????? It seems like what you say about the minus is like we got to have $x_1 \in (0,a) - (a/5 - \delta, a/5 + \delta)$ and $x_2 \in (0,c) - (1+a^2 /25 - \delta , 1+a^2 /25 + \delta)$ which seems so complicated.

Answer (score -1):

to make life easier, i am going to pick $a = 5, b = 1$ so that we have one rest point $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2.$ we will make a change of variable 
$$\xi_1 = x_1 - 1, \xi_2 = x_2 - 2 \text{ and } x_1 = 1+\xi_1 , x_2 = 2+\xi_2.$$  the governing equations for $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are:

$$\dot \xi_1 = 5 - (1+\xi_1 ) - \frac{4(1+\xi_1)(2+\xi_2)}{1+(1+\xi_1)^2}\\
\dot \xi_2 = (1+\xi_1)\left( 1- \frac{2+\xi_2}{1+(1+\xi_1)^2}\right) $$ which simplifies to  $$\dot \xi_1 = \frac{-2\xi_1-4\xi_2+2\xi_1^2-\xi_1^3-4\xi_1\xi_2}{1+(1+\xi_1)^2}\\
\dot \xi_2 = \frac{(1+\xi_1)(2\xi_1-\xi_2+\xi_1^2)}{1+(1+\xi_1)^2}$$ 
the associated linear system has the coefficient matrix $\pmatrix{-1&-2\\2&-1}$ with the eigenvalues $-1\pm 2i$ suggesting that the fixed point is a stable spiral.

i will now now do transformation to polar coordinates $$\xi_1 = r\cos \theta, \xi_2 = r \sin \theta. $$

i will come back to this tomorrow if you don't get to it by then.

Comment: yeah thanks but i think i have to use the theorem... sorry I should have written it before. I have now. Please could you still help...